# What (conceptually) is "Four Velocity"?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, velocity, coordinate-systems

Too many text books (in fact, all of them that I've found including 'Gravity'), just throw out the term [Four Velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity) without digging into what it means, exactly.  I understand $\frac{dx}{dt}$, but I don't understand how you can take the derivative of time against time, $\frac{dt}{dt}$.  I mean, that's 1, isn't it?

So looking at the symbols a little closer, it appears that the components are actually $$\frac{dx}{d\tau}.$$  That is, it's the derivative of normal space to proper time.  So then first component of the 4-Velocity vector is:$$\frac{dt}{d\tau}$$I'm guessing that's the ratio of the observer's time to the proper time?

Comment: I would like to suggest taking some to to consider the *full* implication of the phrase "time $t$ is a *coordinate* in SR".  While time $t$ is a (universal) *parameter* in Newtonian mechanics, proper time $\tau$ (along a world line) is a parameter in relativistic mechanics.

Comment: You might want to indicate which *Gravity* book you're reading, it's not a very specific name.

Answer (score 4):

That's right, but you can also think of the four velocity as just the velocity vector with a special parameter. A trajectory in spacetime is an assignment of a spacetime point $x^\mu(\tau)$ (remember this is $(ct, x, y, z)$) for each proper time $\tau$. The four velocity is just the derivative of this, that is, the velocity vector: $u^\mu = dx^\mu/d\tau = (d(ct)t/d\tau, dx/d\tau, dy/d\tau, dz/d\tau)$.

Its first component $u^0 = c dt/d\tau$ measures the rate of change of coordinate time as a function of proper time, and it is always greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: Isn't the first component $\frac{d(ict)t}{dr}$?

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury It is if you use the convention where the first coordinate is imaginary time, but no one does that anymore. We prefer to directly say that the interval is $s^2 = -t^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ instead of using imaginary numbers to get that minus sign.

Comment: How does just changing the sign on a square change the physical reality?  I've never understood why the square of spacial distances add to the total distance and time distances subtract.

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury you're basically asking me to explain the mathematical foundations of special relativity, which certainly won't fit in this comment; consult any textbook on the subject. The simple fact is that Lorentz transformations leave $s^2$ invariant and, conversely, those transformations that leave $s^2$ invariant are exactly the Lorentz transformations.

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury trying to understand a new physical model in the setting of the established theory doesn't always make sense. Instead, fully embrace the new theory as a mathematical model, and then ask the question of - how the old familiar setting of Newtonian mechanics arises in a certain limit. Asking why a postulate of Special Relativity is what it is doesn't really carry a lot of meaning - it just is, and the justification is that it simply works.

Comment: @Javier - I take exception to you telling me what my question means.  I am asking for the 'concepts' behind these mathematical formulations.  If you don't know them, then just say so.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus - The problem I have with 'just do what I say' is that the foundations of the theory don't match up with the use.  The most basic hypothesis behind SR is that time is similar to space and therefor a concept of a distance between two points can be extended to the 'distance' between two events, mixing space and time in the calculation of 'distance'.  What I can't get around is why you're able to throw Euclid away and start subtracting.  Is $ct^2$ a distance or not?

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury The concepts don't always fit in a comment. Maybe this is my ignorance speaking, but I've never seen a conceptual explanation of the Minkowski metric short and simple enough to write here. Usually it takes at least a textbook chapter of messing around with its various aspects.

Comment: @Javier - I'm 200 pages into $Gravity$.  Perhaps you could point out the section I missed.

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury and it is not true that "the most basic hypothesis behind SR is that time is similar to space". The most basic hypotheses are that all inertial frames are equally good, and that the speed of light is the same in all inertial frames. Everything else follows from there. Using $-t^2$ reproduces observations, using $+t^2$ doesn't.

Comment: @MikeDoonsebury you are mistaken, the most basis hypotheses are the principle of relativity and constancy of the speed of light. In your model, second is not satisfied. In SR, it is. I am not asking you to do what I say, just pointing to conceptual flaws of your approach to understand new things in physics